# Issues reading json from txt file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json string in a txt file and I'm trying to read it to do some other procedures afterwards. It looks like this:

```
with open('code test.txt', 'r', encoding=('UTF-8')) as f:
    x = json.load(f)
```

I know the json is valid, but I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 368, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\rodrigof\Desktop\xml test\xml extraction.py", line 334, in <module>
        user_input()
      File "C:\Users\rodrigof\Desktop\xml test\xml extraction.py", line 328, in user_input
        child_remover()
      File "C:\Users\rodrigof\Desktop\xml test\xml extraction.py", line 280, in child_remover
        x = json.load(f)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 274, in load
        parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 352, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 370, in raw_decode
        raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I used this [website](http://jsonlint.com/) to check if the string is valid. If I use `.loads()`, I get a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rodrigof\Desktop\xml test\xml extraction.py", line 334, in <module>
    user_input()
  File "C:\Users\rodrigof\Desktop\xml test\xml extraction.py", line 328, in user_input
    child_remover()
  File "C:\Users\rodrigof\Desktop\xml test\xml extraction.py", line 280, in child_remover
    x = json.loads(f)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 352, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Originally the json was embeded in my script like this:

```
json_text="""json stuff here"""
```

And didn't get any errors. Any ideas on how to fix this???

Running python 3.3.3 just in case.

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

Just some random (valid) json on the txt and I get the same issue. This os one of the ones i tried:

```
{"data":
    {"mobileHelp":
        {"value":
            {
            "ID1":{"children": [1,2,3,4,5]},
            "ID2":{"children": []},
            "ID3":{"children": [6,7,8,9,10]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is valid as well as per jsonlint.com.

Comment: `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` implies that the file contains invalid JSON. Can you edit your post with the file contents?

Comment: Please add the content of your file to your question.

Comment: The errors indicate your file ran out before the JSON object was found to be complete.

Comment: You can go to http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json.

Comment: @rodrigocf I have noticed, your python scripts are containing space in file name (including directory). Could you try to do the same in directory without spaces in path? Plus the script being also "space-less".

Comment: It feels like there are some bytes in the file that we can't see via the pasted code. What's the result of `open('code test.txt', 'rb').read()`?

Comment: the result is `b'\xef\xbb\xbf{"data":\r\n    {"mobileHelp":\r\n        {"value":\r\n            {\r\n            "ID1":{"children": [1,2,3,4,5]},\r\n            "ID2":{"children": []},\r\n            "ID3":{"children": [6,7,8,9,10]}\r\n            }\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n}'` what is that b' doing there?

Comment: @Jan Vlcinsky removed all spaces and I got the same errors

Comment: @rodrigocf: it means you have opened the file in *binary* mode, and we get to see the actual bytes in the file. You have a BOM at the start.

Comment: Those first 3 bytes are the problem: \xef\xbb\xbf. See if you can remove them from the file. Or do what @MartijnPieters suggests below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file contains a [UTF-8 BOM character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) at the start. UTF-8 **doesn't need a BOM** but especially Microsoft tools insist on adding one anyway.

Open the file with the `utf-8-sig` encoding instead:

```
>>> open('/tmp/json.test', 'wb').write(b'\xef\xbb\xbf{"data":\r\n    {"mobileHelp":\r\n        {"value":\r\n            {\r\n            "ID1":{"children": [1,2,3,4,5]},\r\n            "ID2":{"children": []},\r\n            "ID3":{"children": [6,7,8,9,10]}\r\n            }\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n}')
230
>>> import json
>>> with open('/tmp/json.test', encoding='utf8') as f:
...     data = json.load(f)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.3/json/decoder.py", line 367, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.3/json/__init__.py", line 271, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.3/json/__init__.py", line 316, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.3/json/decoder.py", line 351, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.3/json/decoder.py", line 369, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
>>> with open('/tmp/json.test', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
...     data = json.load(f)
... 
>>> data
{'data': {'mobileHelp': {'value': {'ID2': {'children': []}, 'ID3': {'children': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}, 'ID1': {'children': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}}}}}
```

Note that from Python 3.4 onwards you get a more helpful error message here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 314, in loads
    raise ValueError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)")
ValueError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)
```

Comment: Completely nailed it, that encoding solved it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your code looks like for the second error, but it looks like you are passing [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) a file object and not a string. Try:

```
with open('code test.txt', 'r', encoding=('UTF-8')) as f:
    x = json.loads(f.read())
```

or without newlines with:

```
with open('code test.txt', 'r', encoding=('UTF-8')) as f:
    x = json.loads(f.read().replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: `json.load` takes a file-like object, `json.loads` takes a string.

Comment: With this I still get the "no json object could be decoded"

Comment: Not sure why this anwer got two upvotes, as it doesn't address the issue at all; `json.load()` (*no* `s`) is a perfectly valid method to load a JSON file, *provided the file data can be decoded and is correct*.

Answer (score 1):

As another choice, This will be much easier to fix this issue.

```
json.loads(open('test.txt').read().decode('utf-8-sig'))
```