# Access setup on BigQuery dataset dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I have a requirement to Create BigQuery Dataset at runtime and assign the required roles at runtime. Using Python scripting for this.I have searched on Google for help on how to update access setup after Dataset is created and came across following [solution](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#controlling_access_to_a_dataset) :

```
entry = bigquery.AccessEntry(
    role='READER',
    entity_type='userByEmail',
    entity_id='sample.bigquery.dev@gmail.com')
assert entry not in dataset.access_entries
entries = list(dataset.access_entries)
entries.append(entry)
dataset.access_entries = entries

dataset = client.update_dataset(dataset, ['access_entries'])  # API request

assert entry in dataset.access_entries
```

My requirement is to assign multiple roles to a dataset depending on the region for which Dataset is created as like below :

```
"access": [
 {"role": "OWNER","groupByEmail": "gcp.abc.bigquery-admin@xyz.com"},
 {"role": "READER","groupByEmail": "gcp.def.bigdata@xyz.com"},
 {"role": "READER","groupByEmail": "gcp.ghi.bigquery@xyz.com"}]
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to get it done ? I am thinking to store GroupByMail and Role as key,value pair as a dictionary in config file and read and assign each value one by one. Is there any other best way to get it done ?
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is good to assign access controls to a dataset at the BQ Dataset creation time, but it is not ideal to update access:

Let's say if *'sample.bigquery.dev@gmail.com'* already had *role='OWNER*, and you run the above code, you will have two access entries, one with OWNER role, and one with READER role.

To update, you probably want to check if *entity_id* already exists. If not append the entry, otherwise overwrite the entry. (It's probably easier to do it through BQ UI)

Now having said that, if you have to assign multiple roles, you can have a list of entries.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_id = 'test_dataset'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_ref)
dataset.location = 'EU'
dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset)  

entries_list = [bigquery.AccessEntry('OWNER','groupByEmail','gcp.abc.bigquery-admin@xyz.com'),
                bigquery.AccessEntry('READER','groupByEmail', 'gcp.def.bigdata@xyz.com'),
                bigquery.AccessEntry('READER','groupByEmail', 'gcp.ghi.bigquery@xyz.com')]

entries = list(dataset.access_entries)
entries.extend(entries_list)
dataset.access_entries = entries
dataset = client.update_dataset(dataset, ['access_entries'])  # API request
```

Comment: Thanks Xiaoxia for responding on it. I have tried and getting error : 'module' object has no attribute 'AccessEntry' . I have to assign it on runtime only as dataset will be created as part of runtime process only.

Comment: @Shikha, I've edited my answer adding the code that creates the dataset. I've just re-run the script, it worked!

Comment: I think Bigquery version is different for you. I have Bigquery 0.24.0 and I have to get it working with this version.

Comment: I am running the script from Cloud Shell, and I am using the last Google BigQuery API client library version [google-cloud-bigquery 1.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/). May I know the reason why you have to stick with the [older version](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/0.24.0/).

Comment: This is  just one component that I need to update.Entire code is been built on that version.So , I have to get it working with this only . I searched further and it seems using bq command line,access can be updated easily.but struggling on how to run bq command within python script . Could you please help me with that if you have idea ?

Comment: Check this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#bigquery-update-dataset-access-web), there are several ways to assign access controls to a dataset (WEB UI, COMMAND-LINE, PYTHON, etc). I think the easiest way is probably through WEB-UI; using COMMAND-LINE, it would be ```$ bq show --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET] > [PATH_TO_FILE]```

Comment: Hi Xiaoxia, I have already seen this and trying to execute bq update statement within my python code . I am struggling to get bq update command running within python script. Could you help with that please?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you can get bq update command running within Cloud Shell, now you want to get it running within python script. Is that right? In that case, what have you tried and what error did you get?

Comment: Hi..sorry for responding late. I can update it successfully within python script with keeping the access information in one JSON file.However, I have to assign access based on condition i.e if region is A then access should be access_a,if region is B then access should be Access_b and so on. Having multiple config files for multiple regions does not sound a good approach and struggling to get it done with single file . Have tried storing it in one single JSON file and tried to read to read the access field..but it is not working as it is expecting a file as source file parameter. Kindly help.

Comment: Sounds like a script that updates your JSON file based on condition might work for you. If so, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665403/replace-information-in-json-string-based-on-a-condition) might help.